# Make: expand rule list from file using automatic variables

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Suppose I have the following file:

```
// name: listfile
one 
two 
three
```

And the following makefile:

```
.PHONY: foo

foo: $(foreach member,$(shell cat listfile),bar-$(member))

bar-%:
  @echo "bar-$*"
```

If I run

```
$: make foo 
bar-one
bar-two
bar-three
```

---

Now, I would like to abstract the `listfile` name such that I write:

```
// in the makefile

foo-%: $(foreach member,$(shell cat %),bar-$(member))
```

However, every semantic permutation I have tried has failed.  Is there a way to dynamically compute this rule list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [secondary expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Secondary-Expansion.html):

```
.SECONDEXPANSION:

foo-%: $$(foreach member,$$(shell cat $$*),bar-$$(member))
```

.... I think.  Not actually tested :)